# Synchronous XHR (AJAX) Deprecated?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, caching

I have set up a translations system on my websites (developed by yours truly), which is basically some php files that return arrays.

*hello.php*

```
return [
  'world' => 'Hello, world!'
];
```

Easily accessible through classes

```
Lang::get('hello', 'world'); // Hello, world!
```

This is all fine when constructing a response, however there are cases in which I need to display a translation without having a request. For example I have made another handy functionality where I have PHP validation on forms and I have automatically generated JavaScript rules that perform the same validation on the page before the request is being sent, if that validation fails then I need to display the appropriate message - and there are probably hundreds of possible reasons for validation to fail. Mind that this is just one example use case, so the solutions I see are:

- I could load *all* of the translation strings with the initial request, and be ready to display any one of them. This would be wasting a lot of bandwidth because most times most of those strings wont be needed at all. I could go one step further and cache them in local storage but it is possible that caching an entire site's textual content (translatable) exceeds the allowed amount of storage and thus this does not seem very reliable.
- I could just send a request anyway and retrieve the translations I need, which in the example use case destroys the whole point of having such validation, but is a better solution than the previous one, furthermore if done right I could benefit from the browser's internal caching that is only going to request the translations once and load them from cache on subsequent requests, which sounds nice.

I've chosen to go with the second solution and the problem I'm facing is this:

I have a JavaScript function which I'm going to describe in pseudo code.

```
function translate(file, key) {
  if(!storage[file]) {
    storage[file] = sendAjaxAndLoadFileFromServer();
  }

  return storage[file][key];
}

var storage = {};
```

I don't know if this secondary caching on the page is needed if the browser has the request cached but it does not seem like it would harm? I could use an opinion on that as well.

Now this works because I am sending the AJAX request synchronously. However I am seeing this message in the console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Going on the [suggested site](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) I do not see anything that implies I should not use sync requests, however the word *deprecated* in this message has me thinking.

Unfortunately this is the only way I could implement this solution (via sync requests) because this function is being called on the spot where a return value is needed, like

```
new Dialog(translate('world'));
```

I do not see how I can implement promises or anything in such context.

So the question is:

**Can I use synchronous AJAX requests, and will they perish in the near future**?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is nothing to fear. It's deprecated because it impacts UI (freeze), but it is a feature of AJAX. But maybe you can do it async way - show waiting overlay, gather all untranslated messages and then hide overlay and then show messages you need.

Based on comment, maybe there is a way:

Maybe you can make translate return immediately but with callback. Every call to translate queue string to translate and shows "waiting". In callback you get translated string.

There will be another process - translator. If queue is not empty, it will periodically translates queued strings (for ex. every 10ms) and for each string it calls registered callback. After processing if queue is empty, then hide "waiting".

The effect will be - first request for translation shows "waiting" and last served request hides it. All translations are separate, but served in batches. ALl you need to do is move string-replacement logic to callback function.

Comment: I can not do that because the code that will request the translation does not know if the translation is loaded already or needs to be requested. It calls the `translate` function and expects a return value. I can not figure out a way to possibly do that.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a two-part answer because your question is opening two separate topics.

#### Synchronous AJAX

It is deprecated for a good reason. If you do a synchronous ajax request, the whole website freezes for the duration of the request. When internet connection is fast and server responds promptly this will just take a couple of miliseconds. But if browser has to wait longer for response, the website might freeze for a few seconds and this might frustrate your users. That is why synchronous ajax request should be avoided.

#### Translations of error messages

Here are a couple more options you might want to consider:

- segment translation files by language. Always load texts only for the active language. If you support languages, this loads just 1/5 of all texts.
- segment translation files by form or page or some other grouping of related translation messages. Then load translations specific to that form  before displaying the form. This will reduce loading of unnecessary messages further.

#### Duration of request = ping + response size/connection speed

(for static files)
Ping is the time taken just to send a request to the server and get the first byte back. It takes 1ms on fiber and can take houndreds of miliseconds on mobile. On 3G connection with 100ms ping and bandwidth of 100kB/s both of the following take 200ms:

- load 10kB of data (ping 100ms + transfer 100ms = 200ms)
- send two requests, each one transferring almost no data (ping 100ms + ping 100ms = 200ms)

So picking a solution with loading translations for multiple messages at once might be perfectly acceptable, because you avoid losing time because of ping between server and the client.